# Publishing the QT Project

Tags: c++, qt

My question is interesting. I'm learning QT Framework with C++ but I wonder a topic. I'm writing a project and want to publish it under the GPL license. In this case, do I have to pay a fee for my QT?

Please answer me. Thanks..

Comment: Read this https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/gpl.html

Comment: Where did you find the fees required for a GPL QT project?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm writing a project and want to publish it under the GPL license. In this case, do I have to pay a fee for my QT?

No.

Qt is [triply-licensed](https://www1.qt.io/faq/#_Toc_1_2) ([details](https://www1.qt.io/licensing-comparison/)) under GPLv2/GPLv3, LGPLv3 (free) and a commercial license (paid); as long as you use the GPL version, you are in the clear even if you distribute your application as a "derived work".

That being said, you can always use the LGPLv3 version of Qt for free in an application with pretty much any other license (including commercial ones) [as long as you link dynamically against it or provide the means to the user to re-link your application with his own version of Qt](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#LGPLStaticVsDynamic) and your application's license doesn't place requirements incompatible with the LGPLv3 ([which apparently is the case for GPLv2](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html#AllCompatibility)).